Python GUI client that controls iOS app on a self-signed SSL cert is freezing/stops communicating with iOS app after 600+ seconds of data streaming
Background: I have a self-signed SSL cert for a local server using a mobile hotspot. I start this wss:// server using Ubuntu since the first client is on a Windows computer. The second client is an iOS app on a physical iPhone.
Problem: Everything connects and communicates well, but after about 600+ seconds of data streaming (writing position data in .csv file), the Python GUI driver client freezes and stops communicating/controlling the iOS app. I tried a lot of testing, and it always stops around the 600-700 seconds mark and the .csv files are always around 1500-1600kb as well.
Can anyone spot why the Python GUI client freezes after ~600 seconds (about 1500kb of data)? I believe the issue is in the 'msg = self.receiver.recv()' section but unsure why it is blocking/unable to receive data. Is there a hidden timeout somewhere? I provided my codes below. I did not provide the iOS app side since there is no problem on the app, the Python GUI is the side that freezes/stops.

Below is the Python GUI client to control the iOS app:
import sys
import csv
import base64
import threading
from time import time,sleep
from datetime import datetime
from glob import glob
from os import rename, path, listdir

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Import remaining modules
from webSocketServerClient import getServer,getClient
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, Qt, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QComboBox, QFileDialog, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from pandas import read_excel
import cv2
import numpy as np

from audio_drawing import PozClient
from nearest_barrier import proximity_map_from_png

class VideoThread(QThread):
    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
    send_map_to_client = pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self, receiver, map_filename):
        super().__init__()
        self.run_flag = True
        self.change_map_flag = True
        self.receiver = receiver
        self.map_filename = map_filename
        self.pozClient = PozClient(map_filename)
        self.log_header = []
        self.log_filename = ""
        self.log_flag = "wait"

    def run(self):
        self.run_flag = True
        csvwriter = None
        i = 0
        
        while self.run_flag:         
            # Map handling
            if self.change_map_flag or 'map' not in locals():
                fn = self.map_filename
                map = cv2.imread(fn)
                print(f'Change map to {self.map_filename}')
                self.change_map_flag = False
                self.pozClient.update_map(fn)

            # Log file handling
            if self.log_flag == "stop":
                if self.logfile is not None:
                    self.logfile.close()
                    print(f"Closing file: {self.log_filename}")
                    self.logfile = None
                else:
                    print("Warning, no log file to close.")
                self.log_flag = "wait"
                self.pozClient.mute_tone()
            
            if self.log_flag == "abort":
                if self.logfile is not None:
                    self.logfile.close()
                    rename(self.log_filename, self.log_filename+'.abort')
                    print(f"Closing file: {self.log_filename+'.abort'}")
                    self.logfile = None
                self.log_flag = "wait"
                self.pozClient.mute_tone()
            
            if self.log_flag == "new":
                print(f"Writing to file: {self.log_filename}")
                self.logfile = open(self.log_filename, 'w', newline='')
                for header_line in self.log_header:
                    self.logfile.write(header_line)
                csvwriter = csv.writer(self.logfile, delimiter=',')
                self.log_flag = "write"
                self.pozClient.unmute_tone()

            # Get a fresh copy of the map to draw on top of
            cv_img = map.copy()

            msg = self.receiver.recv()
            txt = msg.split()
            
            if len(txt) == 10:
                try:
                    if self.log_flag == "write":
                        csvwriter.writerow(txt[2:])
                        self.logfile.flush()
                    xf = float(txt[2])*100 + 300
                    yf = 300 - float(txt[3])*100
                    theta = -float(txt[6])
                    i += 1
                    cv_img = self.pozClient.oneStep(xf,yf,theta,i)
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                if 'SendMap' in msg:
                    sleep(.01)
                    self.send_map_to_client.emit()
                if 'time' not in msg:
                    print(msg)
                if self.log_flag != "write":
                    txt = 'Waiting for data stream...'
                    thickness=2
                    size=1
                    cv2.putText(cv_img, txt, (25,100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, size, (0,0,255), thickness)           
            # Always update the display
            self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(cv_img)

    def stop(self):
        """Sets run flag to False and waits for thread to finish"""
        self.end_log()
        sleep(.05)
        self.run_flag = False
        sleep(.1)
        del self.pozClient
        #self.wait()

    def change_map(self, map_filename):
        if self.map_filename != map_filename:
            self.map_filename = map_filename
            self.change_map_flag = True
            #self.stop()
            #self.pozClient.update_map(map_filename)
            #self.run()

    def start_log(self, header):
        timestamp_string = datetime.now().strftime("%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M.%S")
        self.log_filename = "logs/" + timestamp_string + "_log.csv"
        # Only create a new log file from a "wait" state
        if self.log_flag == "wait":
            self.log_flag = "new"
            header_row = "X,Y,Z,angle0,Theta,angle2,Timestamp,TrackingStatus"
            null_row   = f"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"
            for title, entry in header.items():
                header_row += f",{title}"
                null_row   += f",{entry}"
            self.log_header.clear()
            self.log_header.append(header_row + "\n")
            self.log_header.append(null_row   + "\n")
        else:
            print("Warning, already logging")

    def end_log(self):
        self.log_flag = "stop"

    def abort_log(self):
        self.log_flag = "abort"

Below is the WebSocket Server creation code:
import socketserver
import ssl
import logging
import threading
import struct
import hashlib
import base64
from time import time, sleep
import websocket
import os

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
)
logger = logging.getLogger('WebSocketServer')

class SimpleChat(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    clients = []
    clients_lock = threading.Lock()
    magic = b'258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11'  # Added WebSocket magic string

    def setup(self):
        super().setup()
        self.connected = False
        self.request = self.connection
        self.send_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.last_activity = time()
        self.address = None

    def handleMessage(self):
        try:
            message = self.read_frame()
            if message:
                with SimpleChat.clients_lock:
                    active_clients = [c for c in self.clients if c.connected]
                    self.clients = active_clients
                    
                    for client in active_clients:
                        if client != self and client.connected:
                            try:
                                client.safe_write(f"{self.address[0]} - {message}")
                            except Exception as e:
                                logger.error(f"Send error: {e}")
                                client.connected = False
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Handle message error: {e}")
            self.connected = False

    def handleConnected(self):
        self.address = self.client_address  # Set address when connection established
        logger.info(f"{self.address} connected")
        with SimpleChat.clients_lock:
            self.clients.append(self)
            # Notify other clients
            for client in self.clients:
                if client != self and client.connected:
                    try:
                        client.safe_write(f"{self.address[0]} - connected")
                    except Exception as e:
                        logger.error(f"Connection notification error: {e}")
                        client.connected = False

    def handleClose(self):
        self.connected = False
        if hasattr(self, 'address') and self.address:  # Check if address exists
            with SimpleChat.clients_lock:
                if self in self.clients:
                    self.clients.remove(self)
                    # Notify other clients
                    for client in self.clients:
                        if client.connected:
                            try:
                                client.safe_write(f"{self.address[0]} - disconnected")
                            except Exception as e:
                                logger.error(f"Disconnection notification error: {e}")
                                client.connected = False
            logger.info(f"{self.address} closed")
        else:
            logger.info("Connection closed before initialization")

    def do_GET(self):
        if 'Upgrade' not in self.headers:
            self.send_error(426, "Upgrade Required")
            return
            
        if self.headers.get('Upgrade', '').lower() != 'websocket':
            self.send_error(400, "Can only upgrade to WebSocket")
            return
            
        if 'Sec-WebSocket-Key' not in self.headers:
            self.send_error(400, "Missing WebSocket Key")
            return
            
        try:
            key = self.headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key']
            accept = base64.b64encode(
                hashlib.sha1(key.encode() + self.magic).digest()
            ).decode()
            
            # Send response with HTTP/1.1
            self.protocol_version = 'HTTP/1.1'
            self.send_response_only(101)
            self.send_header('Upgrade', 'websocket')
            self.send_header('Connection', 'Upgrade')
            self.send_header('Sec-WebSocket-Accept', accept)
            self.end_headers()
            
            self.connected = True
            self.address = self.client_address  # Set address before handling connection
            self.handleConnected()
            
            while self.connected:
                self.handleMessage()
                
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"WebSocket error: {e}")
            self.connected = False
            
        finally:
            self.handleClose()
    
    def safe_write(self, message):
        """Thread-safe method to write WebSocket messages"""
        try:
            with self.send_lock:
                if isinstance(message, str):
                    message = message.encode('utf-8')
                
                header = bytearray()
                header.append(0x80 | 0x1)  # Text frame
                
                length = len(message)
                if length <= 125:
                    header.append(length)
                elif length <= 65535:
                    header.append(126)
                    header.extend(struct.pack(">H", length))
                else:
                    header.append(127)
                    header.extend(struct.pack(">Q", length))

                # Write full frame
                self.wfile.write(header + message)
                self.wfile.flush()
                
                self.last_activity = time()
                return True
                
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Write error: {e}")
            self.connected = False
            return False

    def write_frame(self, message, opcode=0x1):
        """Write a WebSocket frame with the given opcode"""
        try:
            with self.send_lock:
                if isinstance(message, str):
                    message = message.encode('utf-8')
                
                header = bytearray()
                header.append(0x80 | opcode)
                
                length = len(message)
                if length <= 125:
                    header.append(length)
                elif length <= 65535:
                    header.append(126)
                    header.extend(struct.pack(">H", length))
                else:
                    header.append(127)
                    header.extend(struct.pack(">Q", length))
                
                self.wfile.write(header + message)
                self.wfile.flush()
                
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error writing frame: {e}")
            self.connected = False

    def read_frame(self):
        try:
            header = self.rfile.read(2)
            if not header:
                return None
                
            fin = (header[0] & 0x80) != 0
            opcode = header[0] & 0x0F
            has_mask = (header[1] & 0x80) != 0
            length = header[1] & 0x7F
            
            if length == 126:
                length = struct.unpack(">H", self.rfile.read(2))[0]
            elif length == 127:
                length = struct.unpack(">Q", self.rfile.read(8))[0]
                
            if has_mask:
                mask = self.rfile.read(4)
                payload = self.rfile.read(length)
                payload = bytes(b ^ mask[i % 4] for i, b in enumerate(payload))
            else:
                payload = self.rfile.read(length)
                
            if opcode == 0x8:  # Close
                self.connected = False
                return None
            elif opcode == 0x9:  # Ping
                self.write_frame(payload, 0xA)  # Pong
                return None
            elif opcode == 0xA:  # Pong
                return None
                
            if opcode == 0x1:  # Text
                return payload.decode('utf-8')
            elif opcode == 0x2:  # Binary
                return payload
                
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error reading frame: {e}")
            self.connected = False
            return None

class ThreadedHTTPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, http.server.HTTPServer):
    daemon_threads = True
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._run_flag = True

    def serve_until_death(self):
        while self._run_flag:
            self.handle_request()

    def stop(self):
        self._run_flag = False

def getServer(port=8001):
    """Creates and starts a secure WebSocket server"""
    cert_path = os.path.join('certs', 'cert.pem')
    key_path = os.path.join('certs', 'key.pem')
    
    if not os.path.exists(cert_path) or not os.path.exists(key_path):
        logger.error("Certificate files not found in 'certs' directory")
        return None

    try:
        server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('', port), SimpleChat)
        
        # Configure SSL/TLS
        context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
        context.load_cert_chain(cert_path, key_path)
        context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
        context.check_hostname = False
        
        # Wrap socket with SSL
        server.socket = context.wrap_socket(
            server.socket,
            server_side=True
        )
        
        # Start server in a thread
        threading.Thread(
            target=server.serve_until_death,
            name='WebSocket Server',
            daemon=True
        ).start()
        
        logger.info(f"Secure WebSocket server started on port {port}")
        return server
        
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Failed to create secure server: {e}")
        return None

def getClient(port=8001):  # Remove timeout parameter completely
    """
    Creates a secure WebSocket client connection
    """
    try:
        ws = websocket.WebSocket(
            sslopt={
                "cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE,
                "check_hostname": False,
                "ssl_version": ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS,
                "enable_multithread": True,
            }
        )
        
        logger.info(f"Attempting to connect to wss://192.168.137.1:{port}")
        
        ws.connect(
            f"wss://192.168.137.1:{port}",
            suppress_origin=True,
            skip_utf8_validation=True
        )
        logger.info("Client connected successfully")
        return ws
        
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Connection error: {e}")
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
        server = getServer(port=8001)
        if server:
            try:
                while True:
                    sleep(1)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                logger.info("Shutting down server...")
                server.shutdown()
                server.server_close()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in main: {e}")```

